# .desktop file with .bashrc environment

Tags: bashrc, .desktop, launcher

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, and it uses some of the environment variables defined in the .bashrc script.

If I run its shell script from the terminal everything works fine but if I create a .desktop file to run it from the launcher then it is loaded without the .bashrc environment.

I also tried using the "Run with terminal" option and it doesn't help. Is there a way to do those things?

The content of the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/home/gmarom/bin/idea-IU-135.1230/bin/idea.png
Exec="/home/gmarom/bin/idea-IU-135.1230/bin/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include information like that. What error does it give (if any) in terminal?

Comment: You might want to add your .desktop file, and what is the env. variable?

Comment: Just source `.bashrc` in your script.

Comment: One of the env variables missing is M2_HOME. I prefer IDEA to take the variables from the .bashrc instead of configuring the maven path manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When running from a launcher, the idea.sh script is started using a non-iteractive shell. In your `.bashrc` make sure the environment variables are exported before

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Or alternatively place the environment variable exports in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @IARI did you relogin? Also note that Ubuntu uses ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile

Comment: thx - can't remember if I had overseen any of that - right now I'm not working with ubuntu, so I also cant reproduce.

Answer (score 9):

Moving the environment variables to `.profile` didn't work for me.  Instead, I removed the code that @oliman suggests from my `.bashrc` and then I changed the my IntelliJ IDEA's launcher from this:

```
"/opt/idea-IU-163.12024.16/bin/idea.sh" %f
```

to this:

```
bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && /opt/idea-IU-163.12024.16/bin/idea.sh %f"
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the fix was to move the environment variables from .bashrc to .profile and relogin. Komodo Edit now picks up the perlbrewed Perl from PATH.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables was very helpful.