# How can an application receive system environment variables, even when launched from a Favorites icon?

Tags: launcher, environment-variables, favorites

When I launch IntelliJ from my Favorite icon and then launch a Maven Run Configuration, system environment variables (those exported in `~/.bashrc`) are not recognized inside IntelliJ. If I run the *same* `idea.sh` that is run from the Favorites icon, then they *are* defined.

Related:

- [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226093/) on Stack Overflow, but this issue is more about Ubuntu
  passing of environment than IntelliJ specifics.
- [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114705) on
  Ask Ubuntu about Eclipse, but that recommends a shell script, which 
  is already the case here.

Contents of the  `desktop` file:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
    Icon=/hdd/executables/idea-IU-191.6707.61/bin/idea.svg
    Exec="/hdd/executables/idea-IU-191.6707.61/bin/idea.sh" %f
    Comment=Capable and Ergonomic IDE for JVM
    Categories=Development;IDE;
    Terminal=false
    StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Comment: Related: [Set variable in .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144968/set-variable-in-desktop-file) and [.desktop file with .bashrc environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542152/desktop-file-with-bashrc-environment) (FWIW I don't recommend the accepted answer in the second case)

Comment: Thank you. The first link is about 'manually' setting the env variables; I want them to come from the system. The second link looks relevant. What answer do you recommend if not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Set the variables in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

You may want to study the page [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for explanations.

Comment: I moved the code setting these variables from `.bashrc` to `.profile`. I logged out and in; and confirmed with `env` that the values where there.  But still, the values do not appear in Intellij

Comment: @JoshuaFox: That's a bit odd. Possibly a reboot is needed for the desktop environment you are using.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: Btw, are you running Wayland?

Comment: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` gives `x11`, so, apparently not Wayland. This is a recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS