# What kind of shell is a gnome-terminal started by a desktop file?

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, bashrc

I am testing running Ubuntu 22.04.  I don't understand why when opening a gnome-terminal using a .desktop file `$HOME/.bashrc` is not read although when running the same command in an open terminal it is.  To be more specific I have a file `/home/rquint/.local/share/applications/Sage.desktop` which contains the line

`EXEC=gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-9.6/sage`

and I have the line

`export DOT_SAGE=/home/rquint/dotsage`

in `/home/rquint/.bashrc`

If I use the desktop file to start sage, it runs correctly but the value of `DOT_SAGE` is the sage default `/home/rquint/.sage`

If I open a terminal (where I can check `DOT_SAGE` and it is the value as exported in my `.bashrc`) and execute

`gnome-terminal --class=SageTerminal -- /home/rquint/Sage/sage-9.6/sage`

sage is started in the terminal and the value of `DOT_SAGE` is correct.

I had assumed that the terminal started by the Sage.desktop file was a non-login shell, but if it isn't, what is it?  Is there a way to pass it the value of the environment variable I want?

(In the past this was unimportant, but with the change of Firefox to a snap, sage's method of displaying plot3d output as an html file in a path that contains a hidden folder doesn't work.)

---

Thank you @egmont [(answer here...)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409573/57576) It's a sort of "Yes and No".  Your suggestion about using `env` was very helpful. While searching AskUbuntu I have found an old question and answer [desktop file with bashrc environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542152/desktop-file-with-bashrc-environment)  that also gave me some insight.  When I start `sage` using the desktop file I do get an noninteractive shell, which means I can set my `DOT_SAGE` variable in `$HOME/.profile`.  `sage` provides a command line like environment in which you can run shell commands.  I can do things like `echo $SHELL` (mine is bash) and test what sort of shell sage is running in with `[ -z "$PS1" ]  && echo "Noninteractive" || echo "Interactive"` (mine is noninteractive). You can run `pwd` but you can't use `cd`.

Comment: It is most likely sourcing `.bash_profile`. Make sure you are sourcing `.bashrc` from there and you should be good

Comment: I'm running a standard Ubuntu install. AFAIK that means there is only `$HOME/.bashrc` and no local or global `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Simply `echo "$SHELL"`. Read the `man` page for your shell - it has a section on "Startup Files" with `man $ SHELL` or, for the picky `man :${SHELL##*/}"`.

Answer (score 3):

> I had assumed that the terminal started by the Sage.desktop file was a non-login shell

*Terminal* and *shell* are two different things. A *terminal* cannot *be* a *login shell* or a *non-login shell*. A *shell* can be a login shell or a non-login shell. A terminal can *launch* within itself a login shell, a non-login shell, or neither.

When you tell `gnome-terminal` what command to start, it starts that command *instead of* your default shell. That is, it does not start any shell.

In your first example there's no `bash` shell involved at all, the terminal starts Sage directly, without any shell in the game. That's why `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` isn't read.

In your second example you manually start a `gnome-terminal` with the default shell `bash` in *interactive* mode, this sets the desired environment variable, and from here you start another `gnome-terminal` which inherits these environment variables, that's why they remain set.

---

One possibility you can do is to write a shell script wrapper to your `Sage` command, and launch that from gnome-terminal in your `.desktop` file.

Another possibility is to pass `bash -l -c Sage` or `bash -i -c Sage` to your `gnome-terminal` command line, i.e. explicitly add the shell in between. You need to tell it to act like an interactive or a login shell.

If all you need to do is set a few environment variables, you can use the `env` command instead of a shell: start `gnome-terminal` with its executed command being `env DOT_SAGE=blahblah Sage`. This is probably the simplest if you don't mind having to maintain this environment variable at two different places.

Yet another possibility is to set the desired environment variable in a way that it's already set for every process started by the graphical environment. `.bash_profile`, `.xsession` or `.xprofile` might be the right place for that; alas you inconveniently have to log off from your graphical session and log back in for the change to take effect. (The exact file(s) read upon a graphical login might vary across distributions, graphical environments, method of login, and might have changed over the years, that's why my answer is a little big vague here.)